# light and simple like Leafpad but with Highlight Misspell words and Spelling Suggestions like Gedit

Tags: gedit

I am Linux beginner user.

Tell me please can I find anywhere online the "core version" (if I can say like that) of Gedit? The only two features I would still in it are "Highlight Misspell words" and "Spelling Suggestions", available only for English language.

If not Gedit, is there any other application which could meet my requests? Like for example LibreOffice, OpenOffice etc?

I use an old computer and it counts to use a lightweight application Until now I used Leafpad, but I changed to Gedit for Highlight Misspell words. I use them to write only plain texts.

It would be great if it exists a simpler, version of Gedit, fast like Leafpad or even more faster, and with the above mentioned two options.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibreOffice Write would be massively too heavy for you I suspect but well worth a look is Abiword which has the features you are after:

1. Relatively lightweight
2. Highlights bad spelling
3. Allows right click suggestions for spelling

I would say that it is not as fast as Leafpad but the extra features do come at a price. Abiword is certainly fast enough on my ancient Latitude D520 laptop.

Install it as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install abiword
```

Below is a screenshot demonstrating the features you were after in Abiword running on Trusty Tahr:

[image]

Comment: Tell me please, is there any way to add to any of these Vim, nano, Emacs or other writing plain text programs "Highlight Misspell words" and "Spelling Suggestions".

Comment: Emacs doubtless can do this but I am no emacs expert. It is pretty heavyweight though? Other applications you have mentioned I am not sure but both vim and nano are terminal applications... I still think abiword is a good compromise :)